# Update progressbar based on the number of bytes sent

Tags: java, applet

I am developing a Java Applet which has the functionality of uploading multiple files.

For each individual file , I want to maintain a progress bar which indicates the upload progress status of that specific file based on the number of bytes sent.

How can I send multiple files & maintain their individual progress status?

Kindly send me your suggestions/code snippet or link if already available.

Comment: applet for what? what language?

Answer (score 1):

Keep multiple counters and increment them for each different upload.  (This question either seems very obvious, or very poorly specified).